# Null for an Integer IN parameter when calling a Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a stored procedure where the `IN` parameter is `INT`.

Sometimes, when I need no values for this `IN` parameter, I need to pass `null`. But I get the error `/* SQL Error (1366): Incorrect integer value: 'NULL' for column 'xStatus' at row 2 */` How can I pass NULL when it's an INT.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `links`(`xStatus` INT(2))
    RETURNS varchar(2400)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN

DECLARE output varchar(50);

CASE xStatus WHEN NULL THEN
SET output = 'Is Null';
ELSE
SET output = 'Was not Null';
END CASE;

return output;
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you can write this:

```
Create Function links(xstatus int) returns varchar(2400) language sql
begin
  return 
    case 
      when xstatus is null then 'is null' 
      else 'is not null' 
    end;
end;
```

**<kbd>[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e5d2b/1)</kbd>**